# How does the this c++ code work

Tags: c++

Here is the code

```
int& fun(){
    static int x = 10;
    return x;
}

int main() {

    fun() = 30;

    cout<< fun();

    getch();
}
```

The output is 30. 
How does this work?

Comment: why java tag? is it funny?

Comment: You should read about references.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which part of the code are you having trouble with?

Comment: It means that you need to get yourself a [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: // Juvanis Is it limited only to C++??

Comment: Limited in the fact that it is C++...

Comment: @ juanchopanza:  fun() = 30; This syntax

Comment: I think this question refers to the Q1 on https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/references-in-c/ 
Maybe @Shail wants the explanation of the code line by line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's read it line by line:

```
int& fun()
```

declares a function named `fun` which returns a *reference* to an integer variable

```
{
    static int x = 10;
```

The `x` variable is static inside this function. A special place in memory is reserved for it and is initialized with `10`. Every time this function is called `x` will get the value stored in that special location.

```
    return x;
}
```

We return `x` and leave the function. Let's go to the `main` one:

```
int main()
{
    fun() = 30;
```

Remember that `fun` returns the reference to an int. Here we modify the integer to be `30`. Since this integer has `static` allocation every time `fun` will be called from now on `x` will start with `30`, unless other changes are made.

```
    cout<< fun();
```

Since `x` is `30` that's what you get.

```
    getch();
}
```

Suggestion: use GDB and trace the program's execution step-by step:

```
$ gdb ./a.out
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40077b: file 1.cpp, line 11.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at 1.cpp:11
11      fun() = 30;
```

We start GDB, set a breakpoint at the begining of `main` and start the program.

```
(gdb) disp fun()
1: fun() = (int &) @0x60104c: 10
```

Since `fun` returns a reference to a static variable I can display it's value at each step in GDB.

```
(gdb) s
fun () at 1.cpp:6
6       return x;
1: fun() = (int &) @0x60104c: 10
```

Running a single step we see that we are in `func`. This is the place where `x` is returned (as a reference) to be attributed `30`.

```
(gdb) n
7   }
1: fun() = (int &) @0x60104c: 30
```

Indeed, after leaving the function, `x` is `30`.

```
(gdb) 
main () at 1.cpp:13
13      cout<< fun();
1: fun() = (int &) @0x60104c: 30
(gdb) s
fun () at 1.cpp:6
6       return x;
1: fun() = (int &) @0x60104c: 30
(gdb) 
7   }
1: fun() = (int &) @0x60104c: 30
(gdb) 
main () at 1.cpp:15
15  }
1: fun() = (int &) @0x60104c: 30
(gdb) q
```

We continue the program's execution and leave GDB (though your question is already answered).

Answer (score 6):

It is straightforward : `fun` returns the *reference* to the `static` variable inside the function, which is assigned to `30` by this line:

```
fun() = 30;
```

this means, `x` inside the function is changed to `30`. What is more? It is 30!  You print it by calling again `fun()` in the next line.

Note that a static variable lives till the end of the program: it is not destroyed even if the function returns!

Answer (score 0):

The `fun` function returns a reference-to an `int` type. This way, when you call `fun() = 30`, you actually set `x` to 30.
This way when you print it out, the `fun` function will no longer set it, cause that is a one-off declaration.